# How to disable auto-align of curly brackets in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the latest VSCode for coding in PHP.

Currently it auto corrects my coding style form this:

```
foreach($var as $key => value)
{
    echo 'foo';
}
```

To this:

```
foreach($var as $key => value) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

How is it possible to preserve the curly brackets at the same place where I left them?